# mockmvc: when I use mockMvc to test a controller, how to deal with the parameter Authentication?

Tags: mockito, mockmvc, spring-security-rest

I am going to test my controller using springsecurity.

```
@PostMapping("/xx")
public String xx(Authentication auth){
    String userId = (String)auth.getPrincipal();
    ....
}
```

I have no idea how to mock Authentication object. Or is there other way to deal with it?

My test shown below

```
public class MyControllerTest{
    @Autowired
    private XxController xxController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(xxController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void xxtestMethod() throws Exception {

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(/xx))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andReturn();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Deadpool sorry, I did not get your point, do you mean in body?

Comment: Authentication is an object in springsecurity filterchain

Comment: I think this Authentication is not the header thing in http request

Answer (score 0):

For basic auth, after trying different ways to do it, I found this worked for me :

```
MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post(urlEndpoint)
            .principal(new MyAuthentication())
```

Notice that *MyAuthentication* class implements the *Authentication* interface

Comment: Where is that quote from? Please add proper attribution as per [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Unless it's meant to be a code block, then please edit it.